# Terminology for a partially unlinked doubly linked list?

Tags: terminology, data-structures, linked-lists

Let's say you have a standard doubly link list implementation:

```
struct List {
    int Number;
    struct List *blink;
    struct List *flink;
};
```

and that you have the following list:

```
1 <--> 2 <--> 3 <--> 4 <--> 5
```

Now, in my case, I've been using the `flink` as a terminator of sorts, and unlinking nodes in a single direction:

```
1 <--> 2 <--> 3 <--| 4 <--> 5
```

So 3's `flink` is `null`, but 4's `blink` points to 3.

(Mildly unrelated, I've been doing this to allow for quick modification and restoration of linked lists, and have things like:

```
1 <--> 2 <--| 3 <--> 4 <--> 5
         <--> 6 <--| 7 <--> 8
                <--> 9 <--> 10 <--> 11
```

to build a list of `1 2 6 9 10 11`. I've been using this for instances where I need data to persist that would normally (as far as my program is concerned) be destroyed when doing a depth-first traversal. Think of it almost as a stack that knows how to restore itself to a previous state.)

My question is really just "does this type of operation/technique have a well defined name?" I've been calling it "shearing", but if there's a real name that'd be nice to know.

Comment: Cross-posted to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26978791/3703627).  Please do not post the same question to multiple Stack Exchange sites. It is against site policy because it fragments answers and wastes people's time when they work on a question that's already been answered somewhere else. If you agree that a question would have been better asked on a different Stack Exchange site, use the "flag" link below the question to request that it be moved, along with its answers.